# Rails app works on localhost but no database on Heoku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

First time posting a question.
I recently did a Rails project on Udemy and it works fine on localhost, when I pushed to Heroku I only see signup/login page, none of the 'New,Edit,Delete..' pages. Installed pg and rails_12factor in production, and sqlite in test and dev. The teacher hasn't answered on the forum in a week so looking in other places. Here's my GitHub link https://github.com/guruprasadnagarajan/taskr and this is the Heroic page https://taskr-guru.herokuapp.com
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a heroku app and after you've created the database, you need to also migrate and add data to the database. Make sure that you have valid users and other needed data. For example, you can access the rails console of your application by running:

`heroku run rails c -a <your app's name>`

Then you can create users from there using rails models like:

`User.create(name: <a name>, email: <an email>)`

Alternatively you may create the needed data in the `db/seed.rb` file and then just run the task:

`heroku run rake db:seed -a <your app's name>`

If you have done all these steps above and still have the same issue, I am not sure how to go around it.

Hope it helps, happy coding!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Fredi, I went through the course again and realised I hadn't added an action in pages_controller, did that and it works now. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.